# How to reference HTML elements from embedded PDF?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I have very basic knowledge of Javascript and webdev, in general, so please bear with me.

Is it possible for an embedded PDF to 'communicate' with the webpage's elements and vice versa?

I have created a PDF file in Acrobat to test things. I then created a basic HTML file to embed the PDF into:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div>   
<embed type="application/pdf" src="test.pdf" style="min-height: 100vh; width: 100%;" /></embed>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I can see that I can do a Javascript alert of some hardcoded string via

```
app.alert("Some text")
```

Now, when I try to do the below:

```
app.alert(Document.title)
```

I get nothing, not even an error. I'm thinking I just might be missing some keyword such as [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_this.asp).

EDIT: The Javascript codes above were set as 'Run a Javascript' Actions inside PDF buttons.

Comment: Did you mean `document.title`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox oh,it's supposed to be lowercase d? Then yes

Comment: Yes it's lowercase. Is the code inside the PDF?

Comment: Yes, it's in the PDF button with a 'Run a Javascript' Action. I can share the file, I guess? PS: I just tested the lowercased d in document.title and it didn't work :)